# BeautifulSoup 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do this:

```
req = urllib.request.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy")
content = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
content = strip_brackets(soup.find('div', id="bodyContent").p)

for link in bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser").findAll("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

If I instead do this for loop:

```
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

I no longer get the error, but I want to strip the brackets of the content first, and thereafter get all the links of the content.

The error (line 36 is the line of the for-loop):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 36, in <module>
    for link in bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser").findAll("a"):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: paste your complete code pls

Comment: Please show the full error message. What part causes the error?

Comment: That is more or less the complete code, I import urllib.request, bs4 and re. strip_brackets returns the same text that it takes as input as I have not finished it yet.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The error is at the line of the for loop and I have added the full error mesasage to the question

Comment: what does `strip_brackets` do?

Comment: It is clear that `strip_brackets()` is not as harmless as you think. If it simply returns its input then the `for` loop does not raise the error you report. Since the only difference between your two loops is the call to `strip_brackets()` the problem must be inside that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final aim is to get list of links, right?

this will give you links:

```
content = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
base=soup.find('div', id="bodyContent")

for link in BeautifulSoup(str(base), "html.parser").findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it work without re-parsing `base`? Can we use something like `base=soup.find('div', {'id': "bodyContent"})` and then `for link in base.findAll("a"):`? I've always used it this way...

Comment: I add it just in case=)
I assume that with find() it would work=)
but when using findAll()/find_all() my code didn't workout without adding str() and re-parsing

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to strip out? You could do this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy"
soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url), "html.parser")
links = soup.find('div', id="bodyContent").p.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print link.get("href")
```

Comment: .read() is not necessary. 
From the docs: To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You can pass in a string or an open filehandle:

@MD.KhairulBasar

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you really want.With your code

```
import urllib
import bs4 

req = urllib.request.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy")
content = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%93%B2%E5%AD%A6
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5891#sitelinks-wikipedia
//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License
//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
//wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use
//wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Privacy_policy
//www.wikimediafoundation.org/
https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Privacy_policy
/wiki/Wikipedia:About
/wiki/Wikipedia:General_disclaimer
//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contact_us
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/How_to_contribute
https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Cookie_statement
//en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Philosophy&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile
https://wikimediafoundation.org/
//www.mediawiki.org/
1847



  With Dmitry's code


/wiki/Help:Category
/wiki/Category:Philosophy
/wiki/Category:CS1_maint:_Uses_editors_parameter
/wiki/Category:Pages_using_ISBN_magic_links
/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_indefinitely_semi-protected_pages
/wiki/Category:Use_dmy_dates_from_April_2016
/wiki/Category:Articles_containing_Ancient_Greek-language_text
/wiki/Category:Articles_containing_Sanskrit-language_text
/wiki/Category:All_articles_with_unsourced_statements
/wiki/Category:Articles_with_unsourced_statements_from_May_2016
/wiki/Category:Articles_containing_potentially_dated_statements_from_2016
/wiki/Category:All_articles_containing_potentially_dated_statements
/wiki/Category:Articles_with_DMOZ_links
/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_articles_with_LCCN_identifiers
/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_articles_with_GND_identifiers
1592
```

I have used this command for both programs

```
python s2.py | tee >(wc -l)
```

The second part is for counting screen lines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for link in bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser").findAll("a"):` try using `for link in content.findAll('a'):`
No need to re-parse `content`.

Comment: It's the other way round. `find_all` works only with `Beautiful Soup 4`, before that `findAll` was the defacto method.

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy thanks, I've corrected the answer.